# how to generate a prototxt file for tensorflow frozen model?

Tags: tensorflow, caffe, converters

I want to know analyze the CNN in NetScope CNN analyzer, but unfortunately it only accepts caffe prototxt files. So is there any way to convert the tensorflow frozen model to caffe model to generate a prototxt file?

Comment: You can find the probable solution from a similar post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138481/